# how to use pc as wifi extender with cable

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-transfer, virtual-wifi

so up in my house we don't have WiFi because the signal is too weak but i have a computer with cable internet there and i have a USB so i can get WiFi on that PC.
now i want to have WiFi up there with my phone too is there any way i can share my cable internet into WiFi so my phone can us it ? 
i already used the software called virtual router but it did not work.

can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way - plug the internet cable into a router (get one) and plug your computer into the router, the router will provide wifi access to your phone & everything else.

Old working routers are surprisingly plentiful (check local sites like craigslist or facebook groups, etc) and cheap, some are even free - bonus if you get one that's compatible with alternative firmware (OpenWRT, DD-WRT, etc)

---

Or the other way - only using your computer, set up internet sharing over it's wifi adapter (varies according to OS, I don't know yours).

But now whenever your computer's off so is the wifi.

If you're using a Windows, here are some results from searching for [windows share internet through wireless](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+share+internet+through+wireless&t=lm&ia=web):

- [Windows 7,8,10 - How to Turn Your Windows PC Into a Wi-Fi Hotspot](https://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/)

  - Windows 10: Go to Network & Internet in the settings, then Mobile Hotspot and click "On"
- Use [Virtual Router Plus [lifehacker]](http://lifehacker.com/5983161/virtual-router-plus-turns-your-windows-8-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot)
- [MS Community - how to share my internet on windows 8](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/how-to-share-my-internet-on-windows-8/83a0f2f0-28b7-4f20-89f0-cdeb969612f3)
  a. Right click left bottom corner of the desktop.
  b. Select Control Panel.
  c. Select Network and sharing center.
  d. Click on Set up a new connection or network.
  e. Click connect to Internet.
  f. Click Setup a new connection anyway.
  g. Choose how you want to connect.
  h. Put check mark for Allow other people to use this connection.
  i. Click connect to complete.

Comment: I know i canhave buy a routzr but it is abit expensive becouse i dont gonna use it much i just needorder it some times not always thats why sharing a network was rhe best solutionwel but i already tried ver much chating methodes bur nothings that, i tried works

Comment: you don't need a full fledged router, a device specifically designed to extend wifi should work just as well. they are cheaper then routers. this is the one i use: http://www.tp-link.com.au/products/details/cat-10_TL-WA850RE.html